# Обновление Access token

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Как обновить `access token` при помощи `refresh token`, так чтобы предыдущий запрос повторился? Выполняю запрос на сервер, сервер отвечает что токен не активен, нужно отправить запрос на обновление токена и потом заново отправить предыдущий запрос. Использую `AFNetworking`.

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов - это хранить запросы в массиве к примеру, причем не просто в виде `NSString` или `NSURL` а форцевать строку запроса в `NSDictionary` c двумя ключами, собственна сама строка запроса и булевая переменная, пока запрос не выполнен(будь то ошибка сети, или не валидный токен), то булевая переменная поставлена в `NO`, если запрос прошел удачно то ставим булевую переменную в `YES` и удаляем запрос из "стека". Или можно сделать с помощью таймстемпа, выбор за вами :)